# Пару вопросов по rabbitMQ

Tags: java, rabbitmq

С недавних пор возникла потребность разобраться в данном инструменте,чтобы использовать его в java-разработке. После выполнения простых туториалов и изучения документации, возникло пару вопросов,на которые я(в силу своей малоопытности) не могу найти ответы.
Итак,в документации нашел такой интересный [материал](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v3.0.1/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-3.0.1/com/rabbitmq/client/QueueingConsumer.html) из которого я понял,что при работе с rabbitmq мы устанавливаем соединение с rabbit-сервером. На нем создаем канал и в этом канале организовываем очередь(как я понимаю,очередь-своего рода буффер обмена сообщениями между отправителем(producer) и получателем(consumer)).
И вот тут возникли первые вопросы, связанные с созданием очереди и отправке сообщений по ней. Есть строки:

```
 // Process deliveries
     while (/* some condition * /) {
         QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
         // process delivery
         ch1.basicAck(delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(), false);
     }
```

В общих чертах я понимаю,что тут описан цикл, в котором получатель попадает в очередь и получает сообщение,но не понимаю сам механизм работы этих 2 строк в цикле. Также не совсем понятно,что передается в сообщении(прочитал,что envelope-это какая-то оболочка данных,но это мне мало о чем сказало). И отсюда вытекает следующий вопрос:можно ли через очередь передавать значения,или сообщения, которые я мог назначить сам и если да, то как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
```

Достает из очереди пакет

```
ch1.basicAck(delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(), false);
```

Отправляет сигнал, что пакет обработан

> И отсюда вытекает следующий вопрос:можно ли через очередь передавать
>   значения,или сообщения, которые я мог назначить сам и если да, то как
>   это сделать?

Например так

```
public void send(ConnectionFactory cf, String queue, byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
    Connection connection = cf.newConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
    channel.queueDeclare(queue, true, false, false, null);

    final AMQP.BasicProperties props = new AMQP.BasicProperties();           
    channel.basicPublish("", queue, props, bytes);

    channel.close();
    connection.close();
}
```

Сообщение - массив байт. Перед отправкой объекты нужно сериализовать, при получении десериализовать.

Comment: ух ты,спасибо,многое стало яснее. в вашем коде я так понимаю вы описали метода, который принимает подключение cf, очередь и сами данные в виде массива. дальше,в теле метода вы создаете подключение к тому,что передано в метод, а что значит строчка:
'final AMQP.BasicProperties props = new AMQP.BasicProperties();'

Comment: @Iga сигнатура метода требует их передавать. из java doc: props - other properties for the message - routing headers etc

Comment: то есть судя по модификатору final эта строчка всегда будет такой,без каких-либо изменений?

Comment: @Iga да можно ее вообще убрать и написать  channel.basicPublish("", queue, new AMQP.BasicProperties(), bytes);

Comment: понял. ваш код мне понравился,он понятнее чем в туториалах. скажите пожалуйста, как можно организовать прием в таком стиле как вы написали отправку?

Comment: @Iga тут уже негде писать, сделайте отдельный вопрос

Comment: без проблем. новый вопрос уже создал.суть проблемы описал...ввел меня в ступор этот rabbit)